# Programmatically Refresh DNS resolution (avoid cache)

Tags: c#, windows, caching, dns

Is there a way to programmatically remove an address from windows' dns cache, or to re-resolve it? I'm using c#, but native code would be just fine (however, playing with the registry would not be). 
I'm writing a little application that measures the amount of time it takes to resolve an address and would like to avoid caching issues.

Comment: You can use the technique described here: http://brannickdevice.blogspot.com/2006/04/winxp-flushing-dns-programatically.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure out how to call the more specific DnsFlushResolverCacheEntry